# Having to refresh browser after updating through put request (React js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

For the context, when the user enter a *name* and *number* and click the *add* button, automatically the new person info will be added to the database. If the *name* already exist, it will prompt, '*name* is already exist in phonebook, continue to update with new number ?', as in `App.js` in frontend. The issue now is that as I click the *add* button, it displays info showing image like below. Yes it is updating but I have to refresh the browser to get it displays like in the second picture. Is this normal for it to behave like this ? I include the code in `App.js`, the code logic and code that displays it.

[image]

second picture

[image]

App.js

```
const addName = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    const nameObject = {
      name: newName,
      number: newNumber
    }

    const changeNumberText = 'is already exist in phonebook, continue to update with new number ?'
    const existingPerson = persons.find(person => person.name.toLowerCase() === nameObject.name.toLowerCase())
    const newPerson = {...existingPerson, number: newNumber}
    
    if (existingPerson && window.confirm(`${existingPerson.name} ${changeNumberText}`)) {
      personService
        .update(existingPerson.id, newPerson)
        .then(response => {
          setPersons(persons.map(person=>person.id === existingPerson.id ? response : person))
          setNewName('')
          setNewNumber('')
          setErrorMessage(
            `${existingPerson.name}'s phone number has been updated`
          )
          setTimeout(() => {
            setErrorMessage(null)
          }, 5000)
        })
    } else if(!existingPerson) {
      personService
```

Person.js

```
import React from "react";

const Person = ({person, deleteButton, text}) => {
  return (
    <div>
        <li className='personinfo'> 
          {person.name} {person.number}
          <button onClick={deleteButton}> {text} </button> 
        </li>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Person
```

```
<ul>
      {persons.filter((person) => {
        if (searchTerm === "") {
        return person
      } else if (person.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
        return person
      }
      }).map((person, id) => {
        return (
        <Person key={id} person={person} deleteButton={()=>handleDelete(person.id)} text='Delete' />
      );
      })
      }
</ul>
```

P.S :
console.log(response)

[image]

Comment: Could you put together a working example? Like a codesanbox or something similar?

Comment: @Joshua i'm afraid it's not possible to setup a codesandbox for this it has gotten a little complex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I this should be written as a comment but I'm not eligible to post comment.Hope this would help you.

Delete Button popping out without the name & contact number indicate UI updates after array changed. But there is no Value to display in person.name and person.number .

console.log and see if the values are undefined. I have hunch when you're updating the array with

```
 setPersons(persons.map(person=>person.id === existingPerson.id ? response : person))
```

response object might be the culprit here. You might wanna console.log('response')

---

**Edited After You Posted The Console Log**

you need to change

```
setPersons(persons.map(person=>person.id === existingPerson.id ? response : person))
```

to

```
setPersons(persons.map(person=>person.id === existingPerson.id ? response.data : person))
```

Comment: if you could setup a codesandbox I'll definitely look into this

Comment: I have include the console.log(response) picture in my post above. I don't think it's possible to setup a codesandbox for this it has gotten a little complex

Comment: Just change the response to response.data

Comment: it workss !! any explanation for how it works?

Comment: The response object contains all the headers ,http details and body (data).always remember to access the data part like response.data sometimes it maybe response.body.